# Subspace of linear transforms from V to V

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose V is finite-dimensional and the $\mathscr{E}$ is a subspace of $\mathscr{L}(V)$ such the $ST\in \mathscr{E}$ and $TS \in \mathscr{E}$ for all $S \in \mathscr{L}(V)$ and all $T \in \mathscr{E}$. Prove that $\mathscr{E} = \{0\}$ or $\mathscr{E} = \mathscr{L}(V)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $dim(V)=n$, $\mathcal{L}(V) \cong M_n(k)$ as algebras. So your question is equivalent to showing that for every subspace $\mathcal{E} \subset M_n(k)$ satisfying $ST,TS \in \mathcal{E}$ for all $S\in M_n(k),T\in \mathcal{E}$, we have $\mathcal{E}=0$ or $M_n(k)$.

Now this is a much easier statement to prove. Just take any subspace $\mathcal{E}$ satisfying these conditions and suppose it's not $0$. You can then take a non zero element $E \in \mathcal{E}$. Now play around with matrix multiplication and the fact that $SE,ES \in \mathcal{E}$ for every $S\in M_n(k)$ to show that $\mathcal{E}=M_n(k)$.

Comment: I am not familiar with matrix ideals. Could you word you question in terms of linear transforms?

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove the ideals.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first show that $\mathscr{E}$ contains at least one invertible matrix: Since $\mathscr{E}\neq \{0\}$, then $\mathscr{E}$ contains at least one non-zero matrix. Let it be $A$, and let $x\neq 0$ a non-zero element of $A$ in the $(i,j)$ entry. If we denote by $e_{kl}$ the matrix having $1$ in the $(k,l)$ entry and $0$ everywhere else, then it is easy to show that the matrix 
$$e_{ki}Ae_{jk}$$
has $x$ in the $(k,k)$ entry and zero everywhere else. By definition $e_{ki}Ae_{jk}\in\mathscr{E}$. Let $k=1,2,...,n$, where $n$ is the dimension of the v.s. $V$. Since $\mathscr{E}$ is closed under addition (it is easy to see that), we can sum 
$$E=\Sigma_{k=1}^{n}e_{ki}Ae_{jk}=xI\in\mathscr{E}$$ 
But, $E$ is clearly invertible (since it is a multiple of the identity).

If $E \in \mathscr{E}$ and $SE,ES \in \mathscr{E}$ for any $S \in \mathscr{L}(V)$, then let $S=E^{-1}$ thus $$E*E^{-1}=E^{-1}*E=I \in \mathscr{E}$$ Consequently, for any $S \in \mathscr{L}(V)$ $$I*S=S*I=S \in \mathscr{E}$$ Thus $$\mathscr{E}=\mathscr{L}(V)$$.

Comment: You still need to argue why $\mathscr{E}$ contains an invertible matrix $E$ if $\mathscr{E} \neq \{0\}$, which is the less trivial part of this approach.

Comment: Couldn't this be argued by letting $(v_1...v_n)$ be basis of V then there exists  M, an invertible matrix between $\mathscr{L}(V)$ and $Mat(n,n, \mathbb{R})$

Comment: Jendrik Stelzner: you are right. I've added this point to the proof. I hope it is clear now. thank you for immediately mentioning the missing part.